# How to create uuid in nodejs with payload?

Tags: node.js, uuid

So in my project email must be unique for users to register, how to add it also a argument to uuid generator?

Comment: Please tell us more about what actually you are doing, include some parts of your code to show what you already tried !

Answer (score 3):

You can use uuid v5() to generate the uuid.

```
import { v5 as uuidv5 } from 'uuid';

// Define a custom namespace.  Readers, create your own using something like
// https://www.uuidgenerator.net/
const MY_NAMESPACE = '1b671a64-40d5-491e-99b0-da01ff1f3341';

uuidv5('Hello, World!', MY_NAMESPACE); // ⇨ '630eb68f-e0fa-5ecc-887a-7c7a62614681'
```

https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid#uuidv5name-namespace-buffer-offset

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear but I get the first part I'll answer that if you want the user to have unique email then you have to cross check that in your database if that already exists or not.

You can use express-validator npm package along with that.

Don't use UUID with email. Just dont. Email should be readable and easy to remember not just random characters.